# Non-interacting particles

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $X(t)$ is a Markov chain taking values in $\{0,1\}^2$.
Suppose $q$ is the q matrix whose positive valued entries are

$q((0,0),(1,0)) = \beta_{0}$

$q((1,0),(0,0)) = \delta_{0}$

$q((0,1),(1,1)) = \beta_{0}$

$q((1,1),(0,1)) = \delta_{0}$

$q((0,0),(0,1)) = \beta_{1}$

$q((0,1),(0,0)) = \delta_{1}$

$q((1,0),(1,1)) = \beta_{1}$

$q((1,1),(1,0)) = \delta_{1}$

How do I rigorously show that the random processes $X_{1}(t)$ and $X_{2}(t)$ are independent random processes?
Here $X_{i}(t)$ means the $i-th$ component of $X(t)$

Answer (score 1):

First compute carefully the marginals.

Then assuming the initial states are independant, you make sure that the product of marginals has the same law as the whole chain, which is straigtforward.

Comment: How do I go about showing that the product of the marginals give the same law as the whole chain?  I am only given the Q matrix.

Comment: consider a chain consisting of $(X_1,X_2)$ where $X_i$ are independant Markov chains: this is also a Markov chain, and compute its transitions.

Comment: the new chain will have the same q matrix and thus the same law.   thanks

Comment: you are welcome :)